# How to select rows with duplicate content?

Tags: mysql

I have a table of email, and I want to select emails that Repeated more than one time:

[image]

How can I just select rows (Emails) that repeated more than one time?

Comment: @argentum47 What do you mean?

Comment: the images people use to represent content

Comment: @argentum47 Oh , what fun
Do you like this picture ?
I got a pack of these images .
Kidding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group by `email` and select only those having more than one record per group

```
select email
from your_table
group by email
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: Thank you. an other question, I know PDO and mysqli witch one do you suggest to use in my website?