# How to select all rows with duplicated column value in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a few repetitions in col1:

```
co1, col2, col3
a, d, f
r, h, d
e, g, h
z, k, m
e, s, t
a, b, c
e, k, t
```

Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26627898/how-to-select-rows-with-duplicate-content), I can select all col1 values which are repeated

```
SELECT col1
FROM mytable
GROUP BY col1
HAVING ( COUNT(col1) > 1 )
```

How can I select all rows with a repeated col1 value and order them by col1? The expected result looks like this:

```
co1, col2, col3
a, d, f
a, b, c
e, g, h
e, s, t
e, k, t
```

Comment: Thank you all for the answers. I accepted @Prdp's one as it is the most complete and he/she was the first to suggest to use -partition by-.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `EXISTS`

```
SELECT *
FROM   mytable a
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   mytable b
               WHERE  a.col1 = b.col1
               HAVING Count(col1) > 1) 
Order by col1
```

Another way

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT *,
               Count(1)OVER( partition BY col1) AS cnt
        FROM   mytable) a
WHERE  cnt > 1
ORDER  BY col1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a window function for that:

```
select co1, col2, col3
from (
  select co1, col2, col3, count(*) over (partition by col1) as cnt
  from the_table
) t
where cnt > 1
order by col1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `Inner Join` the result with the original table like this:

```
select t1.* 
from your_table t1
inner join (
    select col1
    from your_table
    group by col1
    having count(col1) > 1 ) t2
on t1.col1 = t2.col1
order by t1.col1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * 
From ( Select * ,count(*) over (Partition By Col1) as cnt from t) t
Where cnt>1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        Select co1,col2,col3 From 
    ( Select * ,count(*) over (Partition By Co1) as cnt from #b) a
 Where cnt>1
```